# Generate list of int to populate ComboBox in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I'm trying to avoid hardcoding a whole bunch of numbers into my JavaFX ComboBox, but I don't know any other way to do it. Currently I'm doing this:

```
length_comboBox.getItems().addAll(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30);
```

However my aim is to make a call to a method that will generate a list of numbers to some specified upper limit (say 50). I've tried the following but it just adds one last `i`, instead of all 50:

```
length_comboBox.getItems().addAll(generator(50));

public static int generator(int limit) {
int i;
for (i = 1; i < limit; i++)
    System.out.println(i);
return i;
}
```

Comment: I should have written `length_comboBox.getItems().addAll(generator(51));` but you get the idea...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ComboBox cBox = new ComboBox();
cBox.getItems().addAll(generator());
```

... example ...

```
private Integer[] generator() {
    int size = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    Integer[] result = new Integer[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 50);

    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Of course, you can change the method generator to take an int argument as a size. In this example I showed how it can be implemented with random size.

Comment: oops - and random values as well... If you want to add sequential int numbers to combo box, just edit the line "result[i] = i.
And - there are more effective ways to do this (using the IntStream, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the one-liner

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1,50).boxed().forEach(length_comboBox.getItems()::add);
```

or, if you want to fire fewer change events to the combo box (in practice it will make very little difference):

```
length_comboBox.getItems().setAll(
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1,50).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```

Comment: Very nice implementation(s) of my answer.

Comment: @zlakad Yes, nothing wrong with your answer, I just thought it was worth showing the "stream" version.